# how to mock import es6 export methods with Jest and babel-jest

Tags: javascript, node.js, unit-testing, jestjs

I have the following module called `index.js`

```
export function iWantToMockThis(a) {
    return a + 1;
}

export function foo(a) {
    return iWantToMockThis(a);
}
```

and the following test

```
import {foo} from '../src/index';

describe("testing mock es6", () => {
    jest.doMock('../src/index', () => ({
        foo: jest.requireActual('../src/index').foo,
        iWantToMockThis: jest.fn(() => 99)
    }));

    test('mocking barProp', ()=> {
        expect(foo(2)).toBe(99); // <-- it should be 99 but its 3
    })

});
```

This is just a small example of what I'm trying to achieve a bigger scale, by design `iWantToMockThis` has to be in the same module, but I do not find the way to mock it and return what I want to the `foo` method.

Any idea?

Some context:

- I tried many things, eg `jest.mock` before the es6 import.
- Default jest configuration

complete example: 
https://github.com/juanpicado/jest_mock_es6_example

Comment: It's impossible to spy or mock an export that is used within same module.

Comment: You are right, here the why https://github.com/facebook/jest/issues/1075#issuecomment-221771095

Comment: Yes, this isn't specific to Jest. Possible workarounds are listed in dupe questions. Basically, you need to either move functions to separate modules or assign them to some object and use as methods. Or skip a mock if it's not vital for testability.

Comment: Yes, It's what I did, actually, it's much better testable in that way. Thanks for pointing me in the right direction.